# Access 2013 - Combo Box, Value list

Tags: ms-access

Hey im sitting here and manually checking in one of two options in a `Combo box`-`'Value List'` - `REQUEST;RESPONSE` for over 8000 rows, its either `REQUEST OR RESPONSE` and that´s quiet repetitive and ineffective the way im doing this! So was wondering if there is a function or command that can speed upp this process?

For example if i mark every row that should be `REQUEST` and then in some way change every marked object simultaneously to `REQUEST` or if i need to build a update query of some sort to do this change...

I have never used Access in this way before, some help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

EDIT
Table
[image]

RDBID = `primkey`, MsgString = stings with either `REQUEST OR RESPONSE`, MsgType = where i want to choose `REQUEST OR RESPONSE`

p_logifles and MsgNumbers are useless here

Comment: Add a boolean (Yes/No) field to your table, list all records in a continuous form with just the Yes/No enabled you can then tab through each record and press space to tick the box.  Afterwards perform an update query to place `Request` in each TRUE record.

Comment: Is there some other field in your table that identifies whether it should be Request or Response?

Comment: i have a "Messagestring" column that has all the request and responses pack together, So to distinguish them i have made this column "MsgType" where i have the to variable REQUEST or RESPONSE to separate them late on @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: @sesar please provide sample data on the Messagestring column, and the structure of your table (any other relevant fields for this problem + an ID field or other field to distinguish rows)

Comment: Yes, sure look edit @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: And how do you determine the `MsgType` based on the information in `MsgString`?

Comment: for the most part is 19 = REQUEST and 59 = RESPONSE, (i don´t show a 59 code in the picture i noticed... but it looks the same but with a 59 instead of a 19 @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: Are the 19 and 59 you're referring to always in the 5th and 6th place, not counting the spaces?

Comment: yes for the most part, not always but for the most part, the once that´s not are insignificant and can be changed manually @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: ok, expecting an UPDATE WHERE = 19 type query.  Are the values in `MsgType` from a look-up field?  i.e. is the field storing the value `Response/Request` or does it store `1/2` (the Foreign Key to a MsgType tables Primary Key)?  It's only a small update to the SQL, but worth mentioning now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information provided in the comments, this should do:

```
UPDATE [Edit Table] 
SET MsgType = IIF(Mid(MsgString, 6, 2) = "19", "REQUEST", "RESPONSE") 
WHERE Mid(MsgString, 6, 2) = "59" OR Mid(MsgString, 6, 2) = "19"
```

All rows not having 19 or 59 on the right places will be unaffected.

Comment: Good. Try putting in a little more information in the question next time. @Darren-Bartrup-Cook and me had to ask a lot of questions to get a good picture of what you wanted, and how the data looked. We're all volunteers here, so try to minimize the work we need to do. More information on how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve